# Shuffling numbers based on the numbers from the row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say we have a 12-digit numbers in a given row.

```
AccountNumber
=============
136854775807
293910210121
763781239182
```

Is it possible to shuffle the numbers of a single row solely based on the numbers of that row? e.g. 136854775807 would become 573145887067

Comment: what's the logic of the shuffle?

Comment: Do you really need the digits of an account number shuffled? If obfuscation is your security, be aware that account numbers usually contain some kind of check digit: It may be possible for an attacker to un-shuffle the account number with high probability.

Comment: is the reason for this - sensitive data? if yes, then won't it be easier just to use mask. For example instead of 136854775807 have 136850000807, where 0000 is always replaced the characters at the same position.

Comment: @user2722968 I don't see how one can unshuffle just based on a check digit.  There are many combinations for those digits to shuffle into, and 1/10 would have the same check digit.  And that's assuming that the check digit isn't shuffled.

Comment: yes, for security reason. I would like to shuffle the numbers let's say before the database being shared to another party for testing. Don't need to unshuffle the numbers back.

Comment: Then use data masking or encrypt it. Shuffling isn't secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a user-defined function to shuffle the numbers.

What I have done is, taken out each character and stored it into a table variable along with a random number. Then at last concatenated each character in the ascending order of the random number.

It is not possible to use `RAND` function inside a user-defined function. So created a `VIEW` for taking a random number.

**View : random_num**

```
create view dbo.[random_num]
as
select floor(rand()* 12) as [rnd];
```

It's not necessary that the random number should be between 0 and 12. We can give a larger number instead of 12.

**User-defined function : fn_shuffle**

```
create function dbo.[fn_shuffle](
    @acc varchar(12)
)
returns varchar(12)
as begin

    declare @tbl as table([a] varchar(1), [b] int);
    declare @i as int = 1;
    declare @l as int;
    set @l = (select len(@acc));

    while(@i <= @l)
    begin

        insert into @tbl([a], [b])
        select substring(@acc, @i, 1), [rnd] from [random_num]
        set @i += 1;

    end

    declare @res as varchar(12);
    select @res = stuff((
            select '' + [a] 
             from @tbl
            order by [b], [a]
            for xml path('')
        )
        , 1, 0, ''
    );

    return @res;

end
```

Then, you would be able to use the function like below.

```
select [acc_no], 
dbo.[fn_shuffle]([acc_no]) as [shuffled]
from dbo.[your_table_name];
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aab76/1)**

Comment: You definitely missed something. select floor(rand()* 12) as [rnd] will always give 1 random integer from 0 to 11

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev : It is not sure that we get a unique random number each time. So I think it would be ok. we can change `12` to some larger number, so that chance for getting unique random number is more.

Comment: ohh I see now. You just needed to create view first in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the utility, but you can.  Here is one way:

```
select t.accountnumber, x.shuffled
from t cross apply
     (select digit
      from (values (substring(accountnumber, 1, 1)),
                    substring(accountnumber, 2, 1)),
                    . . .
                    substring(accountnumber, 12, 1))
                   )
           ) v(digit)
      order by newid()
      for xml path ('')
     ) x(shuffled);
```